# Problem filling an array of objects. The result is always null

Tags: java, arrays

I created a three-class program. In the third class, I should fill the array with the values "name", "surname", "code", and "age". What happens though is that my array is always "null", and I can't fill it. Thank you all for your help.

First class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name, surname;
    int code, age, i=0, min=150;        
    
    System.out.println("How many teachers do you want to enter information?");
    i=in.nextInt();     

            
    for(int j=0; j<i; j++) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the teacher's name");
        name=in.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the teacher's surname");
        surname=in.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the teacher's code");
        code=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the teacher's age");
        age=in.nextInt();
        
        Teacher d = new Teacher(name, surname, code, age);
        System.out.println(d.getCode());
        System.out.println(d.getSurname());
        System.out.println(d.getAge());
        
        University c = new University(name, surname, code, age);
        min=c.MinimumAge(age, min);

    }
    
    System.out.println(min);

}
}
```

Second class:

```
public class Teacher
{
    protected String name;
    protected String surname;
    protected int code;
    protected int age;
    
    
    public Teacher(String name, String surname, int code, int age)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.surname=surname;
        this.code=code;
        this.age=age;
    }
    

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    
    public int getCode()
    {
        return code;
    }
    
    public String getSurname()
    {
        return surname;
    }
    
    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Third class (I put "0" as a location for filling the array just to do tests.):

```
public class University
{
    private Teacher[] array=new Teacher[4];;
    public University(String name, String surname, int code, int age)
    {
        array[0] = new Teacher(name, surname, code, age);
    }
    
    public int MinimumAge(int age, int min)
    {
        if (age<min)
            min=age;
        return min;
    }
}
```

Comment: None of the variables in the constructor of `Teacher` exist e.g. `this.nome`.

Comment: @LiveandLetLive Sorry, I translated the program from Italian. Now I've solved it. Thanks for notifying me.

Comment: *"my vector is always "null""* What vector?

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, "array". Thank you

Comment: @user14584436 - After this correction, your code works for me for one teacher. Here is the result of a sample run: `How many teachers do you want to enter information?
1
Enter the teacher's name
a
Enter the teacher's surname
b
Enter the teacher's code
1
Enter the teacher's age
23
1
b
23
23`. Not sure if you have used `array[0]` just for testing because it will initialize just the first element in the array leaving the other elements with their default value, `null`.

Comment: There is an array, created with size 4, and first element is assigned a value, so the other 3 will be null. What's surprising about that? Besides, how would you know, since you never use the array for anything?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, you're right, I only use position 0, but because I was just doing tests because the program wasn't working. Theoretically the program should therefore fill only position 0, while the others should remain "null". In the program currently that array is unused, but debugging I noticed that position 0 always remains "null".

Comment: @user14584436 That can't be true with the code shown, so you must be using the debugger wrong.

Comment: @user14584436 - Any update?

Answer (score 1):

The `class University` has not been implemented correctly. You can implement it as:

```
class University {
    private int counter = 0;
    private final int MAX = 4;
    private Teacher[] array = new Teacher[MAX];

    public void addTeacher(Teacher teacher) {
        if (counter < MAX) {
            array[counter++] = teacher;
        }
    }

    public int minimumAge() {
        if (counter == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        int min = array[0].getAge();
        for (int i = 1; i < counter; i++) {
            if (array[i].getAge() < min) {
                min = array[i].getAge();
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

Accordingly, you need to change your code in `main` as shown below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name, surname;
        int code, age, i = 0, min = 150;

        University university = new University();

        System.out.print("How many teachers do you want to enter information?: ");
        i = in.nextInt();

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the teacher's name: ");
            name = in.next();
            System.out.print("Enter the teacher's surname: ");
            surname = in.next();
            System.out.print("Enter the teacher's code: ");
            code = in.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter the teacher's age: ");
            age = in.nextInt();

            university.addTeacher(new Teacher(name, surname, code, age));
        }

        System.out.println(university.minimumAge());
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
How many teachers do you want to enter information?: 2
Enter the teacher's name: a
Enter the teacher's surname: b
Enter the teacher's code: 1
Enter the teacher's age: 23
Enter the teacher's name: x
Enter the teacher's surname: y
Enter the teacher's code: 2
Enter the teacher's age: 15
15
```